# Node - Ajax request restarts once there is no response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

Here I have a single ajax request:

```
function send(){
    document.getElementById('result');
     $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/processdata",
        data: mainData, 
        success: function(res){
            $("#result").text(res);
        }   
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<br><br><input type = "button" onclick ="send" value = "Post">
```

I receive it fine with my node server, and also the response does what it needs to do.

Problem is, while I am working on my code, I reach a point where I don't want to send a response. I have a long process in my code, and many times
modifying a module costs in not getting to the end,
so there is no response - and that's ok,
because I just need to read Node's console.

But once there is no response and about a minute goes
 by and nothing happens in my node execution stack, 
the ajax request is for some reason sent again and my entire code happens again. that interferes with me being able to read what just happened in the console.
I suspect that maybe it has something to do with a module called request which I use, which downloads file. But I am not sure.

Also, I worry that I do not fully understand ajax and node - in what possible scenarios would a request restart, send itself again, if no-one actually sent it again?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can attach a debugger to node and then set breakpoints, this way you can stop it running while you read (and also inspect) the console.

Secondly you can you chrome's dev tools (F12) to break javascript execution on an XHR request. This can be done by going to `Sources` in the devtools and clicking the `+` beside `XHR Breakpoint` on the right hand side.

[image: Add xhr breakpoint]

Lastly, some libraries do automatically re-request but you are using jQuery's ajax call which does not, so the re-requesting is happening from elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I just tried Chrome inspection, it didn't really tell me anything - and also the restart did not happen. It did show me something weird on the console though once I finished all the remaining "call next function" - http://localhost:3000/processdata net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE . it's not supposed to show any response, thats why its weird.

Comment: Why not return an error response from the server? That way the client also doesn't sit waiting for a response and can show a message to the user

Comment: But maybe it also causes the restart. Anyway I am developing right now so I do not worry about clients, so I can also afford to not send a response because I simply leave my code open at the middle.